# How to match a substring exactly in a string in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a column `workId` in my table which has values like :

`W1/2009/12345`, `G2/2018/2345`

Now a user want to get this particular id `G2/2018/2345`. I am using `like` operator in my query as below:

`select * from u_table as s where  s.workId like '%2345%'` .

It is giving me both above mentioned workids. I tried following query:

`select * from u_table as s where  s.workId like '%2345%' and s.workId not like '_2345'`

This query also giving me same result.

If anyone please provide me with the correct query. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `WHERE workid = 'G2/2018/2345'`? Why are you using a `LIKE`?

Comment: If truth it looks like your column, `workid`, is denormalised and you should actually have *3* columns, not 1. If you fix your design, you will likely have a much easier time. Maybe/hopefully you actually *do* store the 3 values separately and `workID` is a computed (and `PERSISTED`) column? Then you can just query against your column that represents that 3rd value: `WHERE Part3Value = 2345` (may need to be in single quotes).

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 (which doesn't support `STRING_SPLIT()`) and if the `Id` is the last part of the text, `WHERE s.workId + '/' LIKE '%/2345/%'` may help.

Comment: Or at least it will until the year 2345, @Zhorov . ;)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the existing delimiters to match with your criteria?

```
select * 
from u_table 
where concat('/', workId, '/') like concat('%/', '2345', '/%');
```

Ideally of course your 3 separate values would be 3 separate columns; delimiting multiple values in a single column goes against first-normal form and prevents the optimizer from performing an efficient index seek, forcing a scan of all rows every time, hurting performance and concurrency.